# ios - Integrating OpenTok without pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8, cocoapods

I am working on an app which needs **video calling** functionality, for which in tried integrating "**OpenTok SDK**" using pods but was not able to accomplish the task.

I have already followed the guide mentioned in https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-ios but not able to understand it as I am new to pods.

Is there any way to integrate it without pods ?

Is there any other step-by-step working tutorial or video?